# HTTPS redirect traefik v2

Tags: traefik

I'm trying to setup traefik v2 on a development server we have.

The setup:

Docker serving dozens of nginx containers acting as a frontend for different projects. Every nginx container has a unique domain linked to it. Nginx is running on port 80. Every project has a separate docker-compose (traefik also has a separate docker-compose).

What I'm trying to accomplish:

Proxy all of the containers to traefik and add new ones on the go (new services are stopped/started all the time). Make traefik automatically redirect to HTTPS and contact the appropriate nginx container based on the hostname in order to serve the website.

Question: Is this even possible to do? I've been trying to figure it out for the past day or so but I can't get everything to work. Either the redirect doesn't work or if it does it returns 404.

Comment: Label used in the docker-compose for every project in order to define the domain
"traefik.http.routers.`${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}`http.rule=Host(`${WEB_HOST_NAME}`)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to find a guide that covers this:

https://chriswiegman.com/2019/10/serving-your-docker-apps-with-https-and-traefik-2/

Answer (score 0):

To extend what the guide pointed to, the magic sauce is in LABELS.  It can be broken down to this:

```
# Setup HTTP
# tells traefik that cany HTTP connection needs to be re-directed to HTTPS
- "traefik.http.middlewares.mysite-https.redirectscheme.scheme=https"
# 'web' (or any name) can be defined my traefik entrypoints.  Web is port 80.
- "traefik.http.routers.mysite-http.entrypoints=web"
# tells to route incoming connections to 'mysitesdomain.com' to this service
- "traefik.http.routers.mysite-http.rule=Host(`mysitesdomain.com`)"
# Maps the above 'middleware' called 'mysite-https' 
- "traefik.http.routers.mysite-http.middlewares=mysite-https@docker"

# Setup HTTPS
- "traefik.http.routers.mysite.entrypoints=web-secure"
- "traefik.http.routers.mysite.rule=Host(`mysitesdomain.com`)"
- "traefik.http.routers.mysite.tls=true"
- "traefik.http.routers.mysite.tls.certresolver=default"
```

What seems to be missing the loadbalancer definition.

```
- "traefik.http.services.replica_service.loadbalancer.server.port=80" # "80" is the container's incoming port.
```